# Google Adwords API PHP Client BulkMutateJobService for Adgroups

Tags: php, google-ads-api

Is there a way to use the v201109 api to add adgroups and adtemplates using the bulkmutatejobservice?

I was able to find the script for adding keywords but no luck as yet for the adgroups and adtemplates.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it is possible. I'd recommend using MutateJobService though, it is simpler than BMJS. See http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-php/source/browse/trunk/examples/v201109/CampaignManagement/AddKeywordsInBulk.php. This one shows how to create Keywords, but creating AdGroups is just like this. Instead of building an AdGroupCriterionOperation, you need to build an AdGroupOperation as shown here: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-php/source/browse/trunk/examples/v201109/BasicOperations/AddAdGroups.php Same for Ads, you need an AdGroupAdOperation like in http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-php/source/browse/trunk/examples/v201109/BasicOperations/AddTextAds.php

### More details

Training video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CV_kOTW3ldQ, 
Documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/MutateJobService.html
Official API forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/adwords-api

The official forum is very actively maintained, and members of the API team also answer questions on a regular basis, so you have better chances of getting an answer in a short period of time. I recommend asking your questions on the forum in the future.